# Xcode 6 & Swift - indenting reversed?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I just wrote this method, but for some reason Xcode is reversing the indents.. Have I got a syntax error somewhere or is it a bug?

This is what it's doing:

```
import UIKit

class ChecklistViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChecklistItem") as UITableViewCell

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as UILabel

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            label.text = "Walk the dog"
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            label.text == "Brush my teeth"
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            label.text = "Learn iOS development"
        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            label.text = "Soccer practice"
        } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
            label.text = "Eat ice cream"
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
                if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .None {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            }
                }
                tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

It's only doing this for methods after `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It must be a syntax thing right..?

Comment: Did you try to re-indent it? CTRL-i

Comment: Re-Indenting it makes it go this way.. It also does it as I type it this way round.

Comment: Wow, ok, that's odd.

Comment: It's only doing this for methods after `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It must be a syntax thing right..?

Comment: I wondered if there was an open closure somewhere? A missing } or something.

Comment: It's not complaining at me and I can't see any.. Check this out.. http://gyazo.com/4da4295f00f7cfa95fa46622d1816709

Comment: Just a note. That big `if else` block would be better as a `switch` block.

Comment: The if else is gonna get deleted - I was just whacking this together to mess with swift. It builds and runs as expected so I don't think a } is missing...

Comment: Ah, ok. Really no idea though. What happens if you create a new project? Does it do it there too?

Comment: From the menu bar, choose Editor > Show Invisibles.  Post a screen shot of the function (and the prior few lines) with Show Invisibles turned on.

Comment: Doesn't do it in a new project unless I copy and paste my cellForRowAtIndexPath method from the old one... Something in there.. @robmayoff http://gyazo.com/7c7dd2ad589f147ebe9c5f9de87b6d64

Comment: Well, restarted Xcode. Now it's fine. Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I pasted in Xcode and got:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChecklistItem") as UITableViewCell

    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as UILabel

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        label.text = "Walk the dog"
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        label.text == "Brush my teeth"
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        label.text = "Learn iOS development"
    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        label.text = "Soccer practice"
    } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
        label.text = "Eat ice cream"
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .None {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

It looks correct. Try going to Xcode/Preferences/Text Editing/Indentation (tab) and see if something there is affecting you.

Comment: could you try highlighting `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and go to Editor->Structure->Re-Indent? I don't get what you did when I do...

Comment: However, if there is a misplaced brace somewhere else in your code you may have an issue, but it would also complain at you.  Do you want to place your entire class into your post?

Comment: I've posted the whole class

Comment: look at your last method:  override func override func

Comment: Just took that out, still wants to do it: http://gyazo.com/d97fba2be4233dc192ebab28d5a0258e

Comment: Bummer.  Then let me ask, what do you mean by reversing indents?  Everything looks good posted here.

Comment: Look in my original post, the if indents are reversed. It starts far right in and goes left instead of the other way round. Every time I correct it Xcode 'fixes' it. (only for methods after cellForRowAtIndexPath). Ones before it indent fine..

Comment: Try going to XCODE/Preferences/Text Editing/Indentation (tab)  and see if something there is affecting you.

Answer (score 1):

You have `override func override func` in that last method declaration. That happens when you type `override func` and then let Xcode autocomplete the method name -- it adds its own `override func` and then you've got problems.

Comment: D'oh. Helpful, but not. I'll see if taking that out fixes it

Comment: Still tries to reverse it when i press reindent: http://gyazo.com/d97fba2be4233dc192ebab28d5a0258e

Comment: Ugh. Clean and build again? Xcode might just be being Xcode.

Comment: No joy. IT'S DOING IT FOR EVERY NEW METHOD I WRITE NOW ARGH

Comment: Ok it's only doing it for methods after cellForRowAtIndexPath. Any written before it indents correctly. Any after it does this...

Answer (score 0):

Well, restarted Xcode. Now it's fine. Whatever.